# what is the meaning of the second line in the code?

Tags: python, regression

[image]

what is the meaning of the second line in the code , i am not understanding the meaning of it

Comment: have you tried looking into the help of the function?

Comment: Yes I tried but unable to understand this regression method using log trick

Comment: I suggest you add the equation solved in the second line and specify the question. Looks like logistic regression to me

Comment: According to the documentation of the function (which can be found online here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html), this is a *Least-squares* solution to a matrix. This means that this solves the equation for the right-hand side being equal to the natural logarithm of `y`. Since we don’t know what `y` is we can’t help more than that. Furthermore, the script prints the exponential of the residuals of the solution. I believe you should provide some more information to create some context for the problem at hand.

Comment: To me, it looks like it's trying to fit the model $y=\alpha e^{\beta x }$ to the input data.